# Laravel image uploads to s3 is 0kb?

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3, upload, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload images to S3 via a laravel app.

```
public function createFeature($id, Request $request)
{
    $refererURL = explode('/', URL::previous());
    $refererID = $refererURL[6];

    if ($refererID !== $id) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $file = $request->file('feature_image');

    if ($file === null) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    if (!$this->isAllowedFile($file)) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $name = str_random(255) . '-feature-' . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($this->buildFilePath($name, $id), file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));

    // Store in a database
    Media::create([
        'deal_id' => $id,
        'key' => 'feature',
        'value' => $name,
        'original' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

The issue is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. What i mean is that the **image object in the AWS S3 console is 0 kb**

When i open the image it's just blank.

I'm using this package:
**"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",**

What i've done to get more info in solving the problem is enable logging. I just enabled logging so i've not gotten anything yet.

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to add this 2 packages in composer.json and update composer

```
 "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
```

I am also using same package and it's working fine in mine

```
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension; // rename image
$key =  Auth::user()->id."/". $imageName;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($key, file_get_contents($file));
```